# How to detect symbols in console with WinAPI?

Tags: c, winapi

I need to read file and print text in the console. If user clicks on a letter in the word display this letter at the bottom of the console and display the coordinates of the mouse.
I figured out how to track mouse clicks using LPPOINT and position of cursor with GetCursorPos(). But I can't find how to detect in what symbol user clicked. I suppose, I shouldn't use printf() or WriteFile() and use some specific functions?
This code I have now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main ()
{
    DWORD fdwMode;
    HANDLE file  = CreateFile("lab5.in",GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hstdin  = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow(); // Дескриптор консольного окна

COORD pos;
pos.X = 10;
pos.Y = 10;

INPUT_RECORD ir;
fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS;
DWORD actlen = 1;

char buf[100];
char buffer;
char buf1;
 

if(hstdout==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    ExitProcess(0);
}

// мышь
LPPOINT pPnt; // координаты мыши
pPnt = malloc ( sizeof(*pPnt) ); // память под переменную координат мыши
while (actlen != 0) {
    ReadFile(file,&buf,1,&actlen,NULL);
    WriteFile(hstdout,&buf,actlen,&actlen,NULL);
do {
    Sleep(100);
    GetCursorPos(pPnt); // Координаты курсора мыши (глобальные, весь экран)
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, pPnt); // преобразуем координаты в локальные (окно консоли)
    // printf("\n Cursor Position: %d %d \n", pPnt[0].x, pPnt[0].y);

    if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) 
        printf("\n Left Button Entered \n");
    if (GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) < 0) 
        exit(0);
    }while(1);
}
```

Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all your text has been output to the console buffer.

Use [ReadConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter),

> Copies a number of characters from consecutive cells of a console
> screen buffer, beginning at a specified location.
>
> dwReadCoord: The coordinates of the first cell in the console screen
> buffer from which to read, in characters. The X member of the COORD
> structure is the column, and the Y member is the row.

Using `GetCursorPos` to get the position of the cursor in the console buffer area, then get the cell coordinates through some calculations.